# Instance variable value is not changed in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I already found a workaround for my problem, but I still don't get why this problem occurs.
I think i am missing some things about how internals working.

I am calling *check_modify_rights* method from couple of controllers, and I want to have a variable with appropriate name (@post for post_controller instead of a generic one, like @object)

So after before_filter runs, I expect to have a @post instance variable with a Post model.
But I get a new Post model (because of @post = Post.new), and when I checked object_id s in the method, they are different.

```
# post_controller
  before_filter do |f|
    @post = Post.new
    f.check_modify_rights @post
  end

# application_controller
  def check_modify_rights(obj)
    return redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Please login" unless @user

    p obj.object_id
    obj = obj.class.find(params[:id])
    p obj.object_id

    return if obj.user.id == @user.id or @user.is_admin?

    redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "You don't have permission for this action"
  end
end
```

Comment: Obviously `@post = Post.new` will have a different id from a newly instantiated object

Comment: Yeah I can see that, but I am only changing **obj** 's value, and since @answer variable is a pointer to actual value, I expected to change its value. Am I wrong?

Comment: Nope, you instantiate a new object when you do `obj = obj.class.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Damn! you are right of course. 
I thought **obj** just like pointer and expected it points the same memory region as **@answer**, thus I thought **@answers**'s value also should be changed when value changed that **obj** points.

Comment: Thank you! either i am stupid enough or still sleepy:)
Btw, do you have a simple solution in your mind to change my instance variable in that method?

Comment: easy way would be to use a generic instance variable: `@resource = Post.new`

Comment: But basically, you'r redoing Cancan, which I'd not recommend

Comment: yeah my first version had a generic variable, so I wanted to change its name. Anyway, I know cancan, but I don't need that many features, that's why I am doing this.

Thanks again, if you can merge your couple of comments and add as answer, i can accept that.

Comment: ok, added a better solution in bonus :)

Comment: No problem, +1 are welcome for long exchanges. Up to you :)

Comment: :) sure! why not. It's all over orange now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `@post = Post.new` will have a different id from a newly instantiated object.

To retrieve the new object you could:

1) use a generic instance variable: `@resource = Post.new`

2) or:

```
# in your before filter
@post = f.check_modify_rights @post
# in application controller
return obj if obj.user.id == @user.id or @user.is_admin?
```

But basically, you're redoing Cancan, which I'd not recommend.

Comment: thanks! I didn't notice `return **obj** if obj.user.id == @user.id or @user.is_admin?`